# MySQL JOIN with WHERE clause, not returning all results

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

I'm working on PHP/MySQL based 'Blog Post' System, the posts can have multiple Categories, I have 2 tables:

posts:

```
PostId   Content
0        POST0
1        POST1
2        POST2
3        POST3
```

post_categories:

```
PostId   CategoryId
0        1
0        2
0        3
1        2
1        4
2        3
3        1
```

(I omitted some columns)
I also have a 3rd table 'categories', that describes the categories, but that's not relevant.

Giving a CategoryId (eg: 2), I want to return all posts containing that CategoryId, on the following form:

```
PostId  Contents  CategoriesIds
0       POST0     1, 2, 3
1       POST1     2, 4
```

(Both post 0 and post 1 must be returned, they both have the CategoryId 2)

The problem is that using this query:

```
SELECT p.PostId, p.Content, GROUP_CONCAT(pc.CategoryId SEPARATOR ',') AS CategoriesIds
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN post_categories AS pc ON p.PostId=pc.PostId
WHERE pc.CategoryId = 2 GROUP BY p.PostId
```

both posts are returned but NOT all Category Ids,

```
PostId  Content   CategoriesIds
0       POST0     2
1       POST1     2
```

I want to return ALL posts with CategoryId 2 but still returning ALL CategoriesIds for those posts.

Is it possible to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to separate out the selection of the posts with categoryId = 2 from the selection of the fields - try something like this:

```
SELECT p.PostId, p.Content,
GROUP_CONCAT(pc.CategoryId SEPARATOR ',') AS CategoriesIds

FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN post_categories AS pc ON p.PostId=pc.PostId

where p.PostId in 
  ( select PostId from post_categories where CategoryId = 2)

GROUP BY p.PostId
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked, i'm not used to work with 'nested' queries :P

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution without using `IN` clause would be

```
SELECT a.postID, c.content, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.categoryID ORDER BY b.categoryID ) CategoryList
FROM
    (
      SELECT  PostID
      FROM    post_categories b
      WHERE   CategoryID = 2
    ) a
    INNER JOIN post_categories b
      ON a.postID = b.postID
    INNER JOIN post c
      ON c.PostID = b.PostID
GROUP BY a.postID, c.content
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3857f/11)